What is the movie where a guy switches high-schools to start over?
I remember there was a movie (maybe 15 years ago) of a guy who is unpopular at school. He lives in a trailer with his dad I think. He somehow ends in jail where he's taught how to be a tough guy. He ends up in a new high-school where he becomes popular and stops discrimination. At some football match he paints his face like Mel Gibson in Braveheart. Somewhere in the end of the movie he is on the stage and people are shouting "broke d***".

The New Guy from 2002 with DJ Qualls, Eliza Dushku and Zooey Deschanel.

Dizzy Harrison is an unpopular, high school geek going through a hellish senior year. In an attempt to make a new identity for himself, Dizzy gets himself expelled from his high school, learns the technics of being cool from a prison inmate, and enrolls at a new high school under the alias Gil Harris, to make new friends where he soon gains respect from the jocks and geeks alike. Dizzy then gets noticed by the head cheerleader, Danielle, and helps the school football team gain self-respect to win games.

He paints his face like Braveheart at a certain point, and after a librarian 'breaks' his erection, everyone in school calls him Broke D***. Here's the trailer:



